# unexpected behavior, custom .sort() with always return 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

## .sort(function(a,b){return 0;})

if i write a custom sort function that always returns 0, why is it scrambling the elements of the array instead of leaving them unchanged?

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].sort(function(a,b){return 0;});
```

will give you:

```
[6, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

I thought that .sort() always returning a 0 would leave an array unchanged.

### How can I can apply .sort() on an array and get an unchanged array back?

strangely, if you do it on an array with fewer than 10 items, array order is unchanged.

I encountered this sorting xy points, 2 separate .sort() calls, one for x, then y. in the case that all ys are the same collinear to a horizontal line, it unscrambled my already sorted x values.

```
        .sort(function(a,b){
            if(a.x-b.x<-EPSILON_HIGH){return -1;}
            if(a.x-b.x>EPSILON_HIGH){return 1;}
            return 0;})
        .sort(function(a,b){
            if(a.y-b.y<-EPSILON_HIGH){return -1;}
            if(a.y-b.y>EPSILON_HIGH){return 1;}
            return 0;})
        ;
```

Comment: [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is not stable ...

Comment: Was this on chrome? If you try it on FF it probably won't scramble

Comment: When sort returns 0, that means the numbers are equal. So if it thinks the two are the same, it will no t necessarily keep them in the same order. Not sure why you want a sort method that doesn't actually sort though? If you tell us why you would ever want this, it might make it easier to answer.

Comment: thanks undefined, i updated answer

Comment: Yes, don't use two separate `sort` calls. Use a single one that sorts by both properties.

Comment: @JoshKopen I updated my answer with my specific code

Comment: it is not at all surprising that an unstable sort (as pointed out by @NinaScholz) given a comparison function that deems all elements equal, would scramble the array.

Comment: FWIW though in chrome and ff I cannot replicate your result.

Comment: @chiliNUT yes NinaScholz is right it looks like, sort is not stable. I imagine there's no guarantee to replicate it, but I'm using Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) for Mac